# select rows with boolean array with pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, select, dataframe

I need to select rows with greater than a count number (ie 1) of items in the mac column. 
Then create a DataFrame with the minimum and maximum value of timestamp.

```
a=np.array([['A',1],['A',2],['A',3],['B',2],['C',1],['C',2]])
df=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['mac','timestamp'])
df
Out[103]: 
  mac timestamp
0   A         1
1   A         2
2   A         3
3   B         2
4   C         1
5   C         2

count_macs= df.groupby(['mac'])['mac'].count()>1
count_macs
Out[105]: 
mac
A     True
B    False
C     True
Name: mac, dtype: bool
```

I would like to get:

```
mac     ts1     ts2
A       1       3
C       1       2
```

But don't know how to apply correctly .loc :

```
df.loc[count_macs]
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having fun with `lambda`

```
f = lambda g: g.timestamp.agg(['min', 'max'])[g.size() > 1]
h = lambda x, c=iter(['ts1', 'ts2']): next(c)
f(df.groupby('mac')).rename(columns=h).reset_index()

  mac ts1 ts2
0   A   1   3
1   C   1   2
```

---

Just to be clear: we could forgo the the `h` and just do

```
f = lambda g: g.timestamp.agg(['min', 'max'])[g.size() > 1]
f(df.groupby('mac')).rename(columns=dict(min='ts1', max='ts2')).reset_index()

  mac ts1 ts2
0   A   1   3
1   C   1   2
```

But I like using the `h` (-:

Comment: Sir did you fall in love with lambda ? :):)

Comment: No (-: I wrote this in one line and I wanted to pass `df.groupby('mac')` to a `lambda` in order to use twice but calculate it once.  While I was at it, I wanted to rename columns inline.  I decided to play with the concept of passing the iterator to the lambda... and well, I ended up with the above answer.

Comment: The `f` is perfect.  I pass a single groupby and it get's used twice.  Very simple, very elegant.  The `h` is for fun and could have just as easily been your dictionary `d`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) of `max`, `min` and `size` (or `count` if need not count `NaN`s). Then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), remove column and last rename columns:

```
df = df.groupby('mac')['timestamp'].agg(['min','max', 'size'])
d = {'min':'t1','max':'t2'}
df = df[df['size'] > 1].drop('size', 1).rename(columns=d).reset_index()
#alternatively:
#df = df.query('size > 1').drop('size', 1).rename(columns=d).reset_index()

print (df)
  mac t1 t2
0   A  1  3
1   C  1  2
```

Another solution is filter first with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df = df[df['mac'].duplicated(keep=False)]
d = {'min':'t1','max':'t2'}
df = df.groupby('mac')['timestamp'].agg(['min','max']).rename(columns=d).reset_index()
print (df)
  mac t1 t2
0   A  1  3
1   C  1  2
```